# Are dihedral groups indecomposable?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, dihedral-groups, direct-product

This is Exercise 6.29 from *An Introduction to the Theory of Groups* by J. J. Rotman:

> Show that the following groups are indecomposable: $\mathbb{Z}$; $\mathbb{Z}^{p^n}$; $\mathbb{Q}$; $S_n$; $D_{2n}$; $\mathbf{Q}_n$; simple groups; nonabelian groups of order $p^3$; $A_4$; the group $T$ of order $12$.

But is $D_{2n}$ really indecomposable? I think $D_{4}\cong\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $D_{12}\cong S_3\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. Is this a typo?

This leads to the question:

> For which $n\geq3$ is $D_{2n}$ indecomposable?

I think this happens iff $n\not\equiv 2\pmod4$. Here is my proof.

Let $D_{2n}=\left<a,b\mid a^n=b^2=1,bab=a^{-1}\right>$ be decomposable. The normal subgroups of $D_{2n}$ are of the form $\left<a^k\right>$, $\left<b,a^2\right>$, $\left<ba,a^2\right>$, where the latter two subgroups are proper iff $2\mid n$. Since $D_{2n}$ is not abelian, it cannot be the direct product of two subgroups of the form $\left<a^k\right>$, therefore $2\mid n$ and $|\left<b,a^2\right>|=|\left<ba,a^2\right>|=n$. But $\left<b,a^2\right>\cap\left<ba,a^2\right>\neq1$, so $D_{2n}$ must be $\left<b,a^2\right>\times\left<a^k\right>$ or $\left<ba,a^2\right>\times\left<a^k\right>$ for some $k$. By order considerations we see $k=n/2$. Then $\left<b,a^2\right>\cap\left<a^{n/2}\right>=1$ or $\left<ba,a^2\right>\times\left<a^{n/2}\right>=1$ iff $2\nmid n/2$, i.e., $n\not\equiv 2\pmod4$. On the other hand, we have $D_{2n}\cong D_{n}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ when $n\equiv2\pmod4$, and the proof is complete.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: I would guess that this is a mistake rather than a typo. There are very few textbooks around with no mistakes,

Comment: **Exercise 5.9** of Roman's *"Fundamentals of Group Theory: An Advanced Approach"* is to prove that $D_{2n}$ is indecomposable if and only if $n\not\equiv 2\pmod{4}$, @DerekHolt. I think it's a typo there too, since, indeed, $D_4$ and $D_{12}$ are counterexamples.

Comment: @Shaun This is a double negative, which is confusing! But $D_4$ is decomposable with $n=2$, and $D_{12}$ is decomposable with $n=6$, so I don't think they are counterexamples.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, I agree! Thank you.